# How do I write a string array in python?

Tags: python, arrays, string

As my name would suggest, I'm completely new at this and taking a low-level coding class at my university. I'm supposed to write a program that will accept 20 names and then sort them alphabetically.

I've been going through the questions on here and they've helped all up until this program. I found a suggested code

```
    strs = ["" for x in range(20)]
```

so I modified it like this

```
    def main():
        names = ["" for x in range (20)]

        names = getNames(names)
        displayInfo(names)

    def getNames(names)
        counter = 0
        while counter < 20:
            names[counter] = input("Enter a name: ")
        return names
```

but I've been ending up with an error message like this if I input a name (say "Amber")

```
    NameError: name 'Amber' is not defined
```

How would I go about correcting this? My book only talks in psuedocode and my teacher isn't very good at teaching. Most of my homework has been completed thanks to this website.

Comment: Use `raw_input` instead of `input`.

Comment: Well, that's embarrassing... Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: If my answer worked, would you mind accepting it?

Answer (score 2):

You have a couple of problems:

1. As brenbarn points out, you should be using `raw_input` in Python 2.x;
2. You have a `SyntaxError` (missing `:`); and
3. You never increment `counter`.

Also, it is bad practice to use `while` where a `for` would do, and there's no need to initialise the list like that. Instead, I would suggest:

```
def main():
    names = getNames(20)
    displayInfo(names)

def getNames(n):
    names = []
    for _ in range(n):
        names.append(raw_input("Enter a name: "))
    return names
```

Answer (score 0):

When you take input in Python-2.x, you should use `raw_input()` instead of `input()`. `input()` takes input literally, so it only takes things that can be called in a shell:

```
>>> import sys
>>> print sys.version_info[0:3]
(2, 7, 6)
>>> Amelia
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'Amelia' is not defined
>>> name = input('Enter your name: ')
Enter your name: Amelia
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'Amelia' is not defined
>>> name = raw_input('Enter your name: ')
Enter your name: Amelia
>>>
```

**Instead, change your code to the following:**

```
def main():
    names = sorted([raw_input("Enter a name: ") for i in range(20)]) #You can change the 20 to however many names you want
    for i in names: print i
```

This runs as:

```
>>> main()
Enter a name: Bob
Enter a name: Joe
Enter a name: Sally
Enter a name: Jimmy
Enter a name: Cole
Enter a name: Brian
Enter a name: Ronald
Enter a name: Harry
Enter a name: Henry
Enter a name: Dylan
Enter a name: Coby
Enter a name: Jodie
Enter a name: Billy
Enter a name: Walter
Enter a name: Sue
Enter a name: Leon
Enter a name: Francis
Enter a name: Angela
Enter a name: George
Enter a name: Amelia
Amelia
Angela
Billy
Bob
Brian
Coby
Cole
Dylan
Francis
George
Harry
Henry
Jimmy
Jodie
Joe
Leon
Ronald
Sally
Sue
Walter
>>>
```

This uses list comprehension to get input a certain amount of times:

```
>>> names = [raw_input("Enter a name for person number %d: " %(i)) for i in range(1, 6)]
Enter a name for person number 1: Angela
Enter a name for person number 2: Amelia
Enter a name for person number 3: Joe
Enter a name for person number 4: John
Enter a name for person number 5: Sam
>>> names
['Angela', 'Amelia', 'Joe', 'John', 'Sam']
>>>
```

Comment: Oh, wow, thanks so much! This is much easier than what I was trying to do.